# Geometric interpretation of Stokes' Theorem

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-topology, stokes-theorem

First of all could someone please explain my misunderstanding of the following example of Stokes' Theorem:

> **Example (Lee, SM, p. 414):** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and suppose $\gamma: [a,b]\to M$ is
>   a smooth embedding, so that $S=\gamma([a,b])$ is an embedded 1-submanifold with
>   boundary in $M$. If we give $S$ the orientation such that $\gamma$ is orientation-preserving,
>   then for any smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$, Stokes’ theorem says that
>   $$\int_\gamma df=\int_{[a,b]}\gamma^*{df}=\int_{S}df=\int_{\partial S}f=f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a)).$$

**Q1:** What are the difference between $S$ and $\gamma$ in action? Isn't $\gamma$ means $\gamma([a,b])$ in the first integral?

**Q2:** What is the geometric interpretation of Stokes' Theorem?

By second question I don't mean the calculus and physics type interpretation. I don't mean explaining by De Rham cohomology (exact and closed forms) also. I just want to know how it is possible that integrating over whole manifold can be computed just by integrating over its boundary.

Perhaps the answer of **Q2** lies in the following question:

**Q3:** What does $\int_\gamma df$ mean? Is it a kind of measurement the length of $\gamma$? If so, why its value does not depend on any curve with same endpoints of $\gamma$?

Sorry if my questions related to the proof of the theorem somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:** As stated in the excerpt from Lee's book, $S$ is the image of $\gamma$. And yes, in the first integral, the notation $\int_\gamma df$ means the same thing as $\int_S df$.

**Q2:** This question is pretty vague, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. How can there be an interpretation that's not a "calculus" interpretation? Are you comfortable with the "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", that $\int_a^b f'(t) ~ dt = f(b) - f(a)$? Or are you really asking why that's true?

- If you're ok with the Fundamental Theorem, then maybe my answer to **Q3** below will satisfy you, because the reason it only depends on the endpoints (and not the path) is essentially because this 1-dimensional example is equivalent to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.
- If my answer below for **Q3** is not satisfying, then maybe what you're really asking is why $\int_a^b f'(t) ~ dt = f(b) - f(a)$ is even true in the first place.

**Q3:** As in the quote you give from Lee: $\int_\gamma df = \int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* df$. Taking this a step further, and unwrapping the definition of $\gamma^* df$, this is the following:
$$ \int_\gamma df = \int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* df = \int_a^b \frac{d}{dt} \Big( f(\gamma(t)) \Big) ~ dt $$
So by the usual Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the result is the difference of the function values of $f(\gamma(t))$ at $t=a$ and $t=b$.